# Oracle SQL - Making a one to many join one to one based on logic

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Sorry for the broad title, I had a hard time coming up with a brief way of describing what I am looking to do.  I have two tables (examples below) that I want to join but under a certain condition.

The main table has a field called "DateVal", the second table has a field called "Day".  After joining on field "JoinField" I only want to keep rows where the day value in "DateVal" is less than the value of "Day".  However, if this criteria is met for multiple values of "Day" I only want it to keep the first instance.

In the second table below, for JoinField "A" there are three rows, for the first I only want it to return times when the day of the month is between 1-10, the second only with the day of the month is between 11-20, and the last 20-31.

A left or inner join will bring back all values, the only way I can think of to get around this is to do a complete join and only return for min("Day").  Can anyone think of a more efficient way?

Thanks in advance.

Table 1

```
-------------------------------
| ID | JoinField | DateVal    |
-------------------------------
| 1  | A         | 01/01/2014 |
| 2  | A         | 01/16/2014 |
| 3  | B         | 05/20/2013 |
-------------------------------
```

Table 2

```
--------------------------------
| JoinField | Day | FieldToAdd |
--------------------------------
| A         | 10  | A          |
| A         | 20  | AA         |
| A         | 31  | AAA        |
| B         | 15  | B          |
| B         | 31  | BB         |
--------------------------------
```

Desired Results

```
--------------------------------------------
| ID | JoinField | DateVal    | FieldToAdd |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | A         | 01/01/2014 | A          |
| 2  | A         | 01/16/2014 | AA         |
| 3  | B         | 05/20/2014 | BB         |
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do a join like normal except have Min(DateVal) as a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a variety of ways.  I think a correlated subquery is the easiest way to express it, but unfortunately, the following doesn't work in Oracle:

```
select t1.*,
       (select *
        from (select t2.*
              from table2 t2
              where t2.day < extract(day from t1.dateval)
              order by t2.day desc
             ) t
        where rownum = 1
       )
from table1 t1;
```

You can instead do this with `join` fancy window functions:

```
select *
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by t2.day desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1 left outer join
           table2 t2
           on t2.day < extract(day from t1.dateval)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Would you be able to use t1.dateval where you used it since it is not in that parted of the subquery?

Comment: @user1723699 . . . I had this nagging doubt that Oracle doesn't allow correlations more than one level out.  I edited the answer with another method.